# Typescript JSON : Adding child attributes and displaying against parent item attributes

Tags: json, typescript

Below is the Json which i need to process

```
var oldArr =
[{
"careerLevel": "Associate",
"careerLevels": [
    {
        "201609": 21,
        "201610": 22,
        "careerID": "10000120"
    },
    {
        "201609": 31,
        "201610": 32,
        "careerID": "10000130"
    }]}];
```

And convert the above json to :

```
var newArr= [{
"201609": 52,
"201610": 54,
"careerLevel": "Associate",
"careerLevels": [
    {
        "201609": 21,
        "201610": 22,
        "careerID": "10000120"
    },
    {
        "201609": 31,
        "201610": 32,
        "careerID": "10000130"
    }]
```

}];

Iam trying to achieve the summation using reduce() function:

```
var arr = [{x:1},{x:2},{x:4}];

  arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return {x: a.x + b.x};
  });

  console.log(arr); //Outputs that same initial array

var reduceArr = oldArr.reduce((sum, item) =>
const total = sum + item.201609; // this gives me error
```

);

I have some idea about reduce function but i am still new to this stuff.

Comment: Show us what attempt you have made at this.

Comment: i have created 2 loops. One for careerLevels and another for careerLevels (to get to the careerIds). Then iam trying to reach out and sum each attribute. But after that i am stucking.

Comment: @Rishabh If you have a question about your own code, please post what code you have. Otherwise, it's difficult to provide a helpful answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: How shall i edit it, iam not getting the option to edit the question

Comment: There's a little "Edit" link right below your question.

Comment: edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: I have added the solution to this problem. Please UPVOTE

Comment: Amy : please upvote my question as its fully described and i have also created the solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why noone attempted this question. Although people were quick to downvote.
I have created below code to get the desired result :

```
 var oldArr =
       {

       "careerLevel": "Associate",
       "careerLevels": [
           {
               "201609": 21,
               "201610": 22,
               "201611": 23,
               "careerID": "10000120"
           },
           {
               "201609": 31,
               "201610": 32,
               "201611": 33,
               "careerID": "10000130"
           }]
   };



   var finalSummedJson = JSON.stringify(SummationProcessing(oldArr));
   return finalSummedJson;


}

// Summation Logic

 function SummationProcessing(oldArr) {
  let sumArr = [];
  let allKeysInLevels = Object.keys(oldArr.careerLevels[0]);
  let uniqueKeys = allKeysInLevels.filter((key, index) => {
      return parseInt(key) > 0 && allKeysInLevels.indexOf(key) == index
  });

  uniqueKeys.forEach(uniqueKey => {
      var sumKey = oldArr.careerLevels.reduce((acc, val) => {
          return acc + val[uniqueKey];
      }, 0);

      sumArr.push(sumKey);
  });

  var reducedData = oldArr.careerLevels.reduce((redArr, inpArr) => {
      var keysToFilter = Object.keys(inpArr);
      var keyysss = keysToFilter.filter((key, index) => { return parseInt(key) > 0 && keysToFilter.indexOf(key) == index });
      keyysss.forEach((element, i) => {
          if (!redArr[element]) {
              redArr[element] = sumArr[i];
          }
          // });
      });
      return redArr;

  }, {});
  // console.log("reducedData", JSON.stringify(reducedData));

  Object.keys(reducedData).forEach(key => { oldArr[key] = reducedData[key] });
  return oldArr;

  // console.log("finalArr", oldArr);
}
```

The final result was :

> {
>       "201609": 52,
>       "201610": 54,
>       "201611": 56,
>       "careerLevel": "Associate",
>       "careerLevels": [{
>           "201609": 21,
>           "201610": 22,
>           "201611": 23,
>           "careerID": "10000120"
>       }, {
>           "201609": 31,
>           "201610": 32,
>           "201611": 33,
>           "careerID": "10000130"
>       }]
>   }